# Position imageView between two views and dynamically resize it to fit?

Tags: android

I have a simple layout with two buttons and a image view contained in a ConstraintLayout. The image view shows a vector graphic and is position between the two buttons horizontally.

```
____________
| Button    |
------------
____________
| ImageView |
------------
____________
| Button    |
------------
```

The problem is that I cant seem to figure out how to properly constrain the image view vertically between the two buttons.

As long as I have layout_width and layout_height for the image view set to `wrap_content` the result will vary depending on the aspect ratio of the device display. I could set hardcoded height and width values but that also seems like a bad idea.

Isnt there some way to dynamically resize the ImageView based on the constraints?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonTop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttonBottom"/>
```

This works on tall aspect ratio devices but on small ones the bottom and/or top buttons overlap the imageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set  Imageview

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonTop"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttonBottom"
```

height will be adjust based on devices size

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `ImageView` layout size to `match_constraint`.
Just set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `0dp`. In this way the layout size will be as big as the set constraints allows it to be.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonTop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttonBottom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your layout width should be 0dp (match constraints).